# Spelling mistakes in the file?

Tags: command-line, spell-checking

I have a file with spelling mistakes in it. It has a lot of mistakes I need to find all mistakes and correct them.

I used :

```
spell [filename]
```

it shows me spelling mistakes

```
thiis
iz
wurse
...
```

and many others.
How can I correct all mistakes in one command?

Comment: Are you sir tin you went to automatically correct all miss spilled words? You will miss out on a lot of correctly spelled words that are in the wrong place, or you'll have the auto-correct put correctly spelled wrong words in place of incorrectly-spelled words. It's a hard task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a man entry for spell, or ispell, but I did find a [ComputerHope entry](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uspell.htm), which I'll quote:

> spell is essentially a wrapper for the much more complex ispell
>   utility. However, unlike ispell (or the very similar GNU program,
>   aspell), spell does not make any spelling suggestions. It only reports
>   which words were misspelled.

In other words, you can't use `spell` to correct mistakes.